# Why doesn't the yeoman angularfire generator work from the start?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

After doing the generator-angularfire installation and running grunt and grunt serve, I'm getting errors that angular is not defined in all of the JS files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u6d3bfn854iso2/Screenshot%202014-10-31%2012.40.18.png?dl=0

I'm going to assume that the generator works because it's maintained by firebase (https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire).

That said, I followed these exact instructions from the README and it isn't working:

Install generator-angularfire:

```
npm install -g generator-angularfire
```

Make a new directory, and cd into it:

```
mkdir my-new-project && cd $_
```

Run yo angularfire, optionally passing an app name:

```
yo angularfire [app-name]
```

Run grunt for building and grunt serve for preview

Answer (score 3):

i believe there is a bug in the most recent generator-angularfire where it doesn't list bower or grunt-cli as a dependency. so do the following and try again before yo:

```
npm install -g bower grunt-cli
```